# How can work items from TFS be exported as XML in eclipse

Tags: tfs

I've been looking all over the results but couldn't find an answer I have a work item & I need that to be exported into an XML file & store somewhere on my disk. It can be done using Visual studio, but I'm running TFS on Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

(if you're on windows...) You can do this with wiql and the tfpt powertool.
e.g.

```
tfpt query /collection:$coll /wiql:$query02 /include:data /format:xml
```

---

team foundation power tools [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35775)

this adds a tfpt tool to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools.
You can then either write your own wiql (work item query language) or run one of your existing TFS queries. Use the /format:xml switch and you get your xml output. I run the example above in a powershell script and I redirect the output to a tmp folder, but you can run it from a normal cmd window too.

Comment: what is this query & where should this query be executed ? Could you just put down those steps in your answer?

Comment: $coll is yoru collectionuri, 
$queryPath= "TeamProjectName/Shared Queries/QueryName". Then run:   
`tfpt query /collection:$coll $queryPath /include:data /format:xml >>D:\Logs\Workitems.xml`