# Export work item as XML from TFS

Tags: c#, .net, xml, tfs

I am trying to export a work item(Not a work item type) in XML format from TFS.

I know for a fact that if I want to export a work item type template, there are tools to help me with that.

My workaround for exporting work items as XML was to access the work items myself and create a new XML doc from them.

In my research I saw a lot of mention for power tools and I found this link to be useful:

[How can work items from TFS be exported as XML in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457975/how-can-work-items-from-tfs-be-exported-as-xml-in-eclipse)

However, is there any way to help me programatically fetch the work item as an XML?

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically access the data in TFS and VSO using the Object Model or the REST API. From there you can generate whatever you want in your xml.